# How To Turn Location Service On

Tags: iphone, ios, service, location

How can I turn Location Services back on from the actual app when someone declined the first time. I have an option to turn it off or on.

Answer (score 3):

You can only prompt them to the screen to turn on location services like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

Comment: What if I wanted to turn it off?

Comment: It should just take them to the settings menu. So you it shouldn't matter if you want it on or off. Just check if it on and if so prompt them to go to the menu and turn it off. Apple doesn't really like this, they prefer it is optimized to work with or without but I don't think it's grounds for rejection.

Comment: This only worked in iOS 5. The best you can do now is provide a dialog with instructions.